# How do I use a a seperate javascript file on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a game with html/javascript, I'm trying to keep the javascript for the game in a different file than the html. With the local files it works perfectly with:

`<script src="coffee_brewers_v2.0.js"></script>`

the .js file being in the same directory

however, when I try and translate that to a page my website: http://wdixon.droppages.com/coffee_brewers_v2

with the .js file at http://wdixon.droppages.com/coffee_brewers_v2_js

the javascript functions no longer work.

I've tried 3 different tags:

```
<script src="coffee_brewers_v2_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/coffee_brewers_v2_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://wdixon.droppages.com/coffee_brewers_v2_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

None have worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please use F12 or ctrl+k to look at the console output: http://wdixon.droppages.com/coffee_brewers_v2.0.js is broken.

Comment: Your javascript file is linked correctly, but it's full of HTML tags so throws errors galore.

Comment: When you click on http://wdixon.droppages.com/coffee_brewers_v2.0.js and view the source, you should not see html markup. How do you have a `<html><head><body>` in a js file?

Comment: oh, that's weird, I didn't write that. It's doing it automatically.

Comment: I use Sublime Text 2 to write my code and save the file, I'm using javascript as the syntax tho and it's got a .js extension, could the editor being doing this? Those html tags dont show up in my editor when I edit the page

Comment: I've had an idea, it might be that the file name contains a '.' I'm changing that right now, see if it works when it updates

Comment: :( I did a bit of experimenting with changing file names, no luck tho. I might just have to put in the entire script in the html file between script tags... I feel defeated

Answer (score -1):

> http://wdixon.droppages.com/coffee_brewers_v2.0.js
>   is not a valid js file. It seems to be a html document.

When I paste the plain content of the provided js file, JSLint also throws an error:

```
function refreshLocation(){ if(venues > 0){ document.getElementById("Locations").innerHTML = "Locations: " + venues + "
```

So, two things to do here:
1. fix the file :-)
2. fix the js erros

Comment: how can I make it a valid js file?

Comment: Remove the HTML from it.

Comment: The html is within strings and is important because I want, say a button to appear at a certain time, and so I have to write that button in html

Comment: could it be that document.getElementById no longer works because said document is on a different webpage?

Because like I said before, I've run the entire program with local files and it works perfectly as two separate files.

Comment: Again, the provided js file (which is no longer available) can't work because it is not in plain text, it doesn't matter if you create html tags with js, because those tags should be inside of quotes.